# How do I get rid of black bars around windows?

Tags: unity, suspend, 16.10, compositing

Ever since I upgraded to 16.10, after I suspend, drop shadows from the compositor are just black bars:

[image: large black window borders]

I don't think this is an X or kernel bug, because if I run `DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace`, the glitches go away, and everything is normal. However, this is annoying to run and tends to freeze the computer for a solid 60 seconds.

Is there some unity / compiz settings I need to adjust to fix this?

Comment: Do you still have this problem? Presumably you are not using 16.10 any more...

Answer (score 0):

I had issues like this a while back after a resume.

I updated to the latest kernel (which was 4.8 stable at the time) and the issues were gone.  The fix was most likely because of updated graphics drivers.

Without knowing more about your machine, this is your best bet (assuming you are running Intel integrated graphics, and not Nvidia or something that needs a proprietary driver).